# How to get all my iPhone apps onto my iPod touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod-touch, data-synchronization

I've been using an iPhone 4 for a while now and have a bunch of apps, each with its own data. I just got an iPod touch and I wanted to have the same apps/data on it as well. The iPhone 4 is synced and backed up to iCloud.

When I set up the iPod, I chose to use iCloud and I tried "restoring" from an iCloud backup. After the set up process though, the only apps on the iPod were the default ones. Furthermore, it seems like none of my settings transfered over either. For example, I have exchange set up on the iPhone 4 and now it seems that I need to manually create this account on the iPod touch.

Is there any way to get the two devices to sync automatically via iCloud (or at least the first time to get all my apps/data on the iPod)? What if I was using iTunes instead of iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

If you back up to iTunes, it should work to restore that backup onto the iPod touch. I've had success using that to migrate my first iPod touch to my second iPod touch and again to my iPhone 4S.

You should note that this restore will bring the device name along with it, so you'll have two devices with your iPhone's name.

Comment: So is there no way to do the same thing with iCloud?

Comment: @Senseful I've never tried using iCloud with that. I use iTunes Match and not much else in iCloud. I backed up to iCloud for a week with my iPod touch, but I stopped before I got my iPhone (partly because I knew iTunes backup/restores worked across devices and I didn't want it to mess up).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can restore your iPod Touch from iCloud, you need the latest 5.x iOS on device. And of course you can do it with iTunes.
After restoring verify iCloud setting on iPod so you have two devices synced to one iCloud account with one AppleId.